# Is it correct to say "Postal Package"?

Tags: terminology

I am trying to find a name for packages received from carriers like USPS, UPS, FedEx, etc. Is it correct way to name it as "postal package"? I can't name it just as Package, because it is used for warehouse packages and I want to distinguish between them

Comment: In the US, "postal" generally implies USPS.

Comment: "Carrier package" (one delivered by a carrier) might work.

Answer (score 2):

**parcel**

a wrapped bundle : package

```
The parcel was shipped today.
```

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parcel)